# Custom view on a ToolBar v-21

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I added a custom view on the toolbar using this

```
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.general_options_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.action_bar_title_main_ar, null);
        actionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

and it works fine. But the layout that I'm using it must show the the textView in it on the RIGHT, but actually it shows it on the left !!!
How to make the text on the right side when the language is for example in Arabic ?? 
Here is the **action_bar_title_main_ar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mytext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="@string/preferences"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textColor="@color/orange"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it.
Just I added a TextView inside my toolBar in the toolbar.xml layout and aligned the textView to be at the end like so:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/preferences"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/orange"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_below="@id/general_options_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: the key is `android:layout_gravity="end"`